# Localization $(R_{\mathfrak p})_{\mathfrak q}$ for an Artinian ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

> Let $R$ be an Artinian ring, and let $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$ be distinct prime ideals of $R$. I have to prove that $(R_{\mathfrak p})_{\mathfrak q}=0$.

What I have done is the following: Since $R$ is Artinian we have $\dim R=0$, so every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal, so $\mathfrak p\not\subset\mathfrak q$ and vice versa. If we localize at $\mathfrak p$ we invert all elements outside of $\mathfrak p$, so we invert at least one element of $\mathfrak q$. Then $\mathfrak qR_{\mathfrak p}$ contains a unit and thus equals $R_{\mathfrak p}$, so if we localize at $\mathfrak qR_{\mathfrak p}$ we invert everything outside $\mathfrak qR_{\mathfrak p}=R_{\mathfrak p}$, so we invert seemingly invert..nothing. This doesn't make sense.

Can somebody offer some help? It is much appreciated.

Comment: @Whoever was here just now with a comment, I have added a screenshot.

Comment: @Manos Well yes, he has been using that notation for a while now. Do you have any suggestion for what else it might be? Of course it's actually localization at $qR_p$, but I'm sure that's what you mean.

Comment: @Manos And this makes it the zero ring? Is there a nicer way out here?

Comment: Ah! In his definition he demands that $1\in S$, which is certainly not fulfilled here. He never explicitly defines $R_{\emptyset}=0$, but I have no idea how to work around this in another way.

Comment: I agree. Thanks.

Comment: So as the answer shows, the notation $(R_p)_q$ is localization of the $R$-module $R_p$ at the prime ideal $q$. That makes a lot of sense of course.

Comment: @Manos Also of the *ring* $R_p$ at the prime ideal $q$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Let $f:R\to R_{\mathfrak p}$ be the canonical homomorphism and $S=f(R\setminus\mathfrak q)\subset R_{\mathfrak p}$. Then $S$ is a multiplicative set, and $S^{-1}R_{\mathfrak p}=0$. (By definition, $(R_{\mathfrak p})_{\mathfrak q}=S^{-1}R_{\mathfrak p}$.)

In order to prove this we want to show that $\frac01\in S$, that is, there is $a\in R\setminus\mathfrak q$ and $b\in R\setminus\mathfrak p$ such that $ab=0$.
Denote by $\mathfrak m_1,\dots,\mathfrak m_t$ the maximal ideals of $R$ others that $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$. Now we can pick $x\in\mathfrak p\setminus\mathfrak q$ and $y\in(\mathfrak q\cap\mathfrak m_1\cap\cdots\cap\mathfrak m_t)\setminus\mathfrak p$. Then $xy\in\mathfrak p\cap\mathfrak q\cap\mathfrak m_1\cap\cdots\cap\mathfrak m_t$, so it is nilpotent, that is, there is $k\ge1$ such that $x^ky^k=0$. Now set $a=x^k$ and $b=y^k$.

Comment: This is nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this answer comes some 2 years too late, but I thought I'd post it nontheless for completeness sake now that I've stumbled upon this question. Here is an alternative way to see what is going on.

One can decompose Artinian rings as finite products of local Artinian rings, whose localizations are trivial, and taking localization commutes with taking the product. One possible explicit realization of this is as follows.

First suppose that $R=(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is local Artinian. Then $\mathfrak{m}$ is the only prime of $R$ and $R\setminus\mathfrak{m} = R^{\times}$, hence $R_\mathfrak{m}\cong R$. Next, for a general Artinian ring $R$, let $R=\prod_{i=1}^n R_i$ be its decomposition into Artin local rings $(R_i,\mathfrak{m}_i)$. The primes of $R$ have the form $\mathfrak{p}_i:=R_1\times\dots\times R_{i-1}\times\mathfrak{m}_i\times R_{i+1}\times\dots\times R_n$, $1\leq i\leq n$. Hence $R_{\mathfrak{p}_i}\cong R_i$ and if you take a different prime $\mathfrak{p_j}$, $j\neq i$, then $(R_{\mathfrak{p}_i})_{\mathfrak{p}_j} \cong R_i^{-1}R_i=0$ because $R_i\ni 0$.